# Give an image a new X and Y postion every 1 second

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying change the image LayoutX and LayoutY positions ever 1 second. But I cant find any (timer) method suitable for this. I am looking for something similar to the JavaScript "setInterval" that simply lets me create a "timer cycle" using Java or JavaFX.

Any advice are widely appriciated!

Answer (score 2):

With `java.util.Timer` you can schedule such a task.

The method `timer.schedule()` executes a task only ones. To repeat your task
use the method `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()`.

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello");
   }
 }, 1000, 1000);
```

The second parameter of `scheduleAtFixedRate()` is the delay before the first execution in milliseconds and the last parameter is the interval between the tasks being executed in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) with `INDEFINITE` cycle count for this purpose.

Example:

```
Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), evt -> {
    // toggle image postion
    imageView.setLayoutX(200 - imageView.getLayoutX());
    imageView.setLayoutY(200 - imageView.getLayoutY());
}));
tl.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
tl.play();
```

This guaranties the event handler runs on the JavaFX application thread.